# Python Pandas: Importing stacked dictionary of lists to create multi-indexed DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I've imported some data into a stacked dictionary of lists, which is structured like this:

Structure 1:

```
{product_name : {category_name : { column_title_1 :[val1,val2,val3], column_title_2 :["string 1","string 2","string 3"], column_title_3 :["string 1a","string 2b","string 3c"] }}}
```

Structure 2:

```
{product_name : { column_title_1 :[val1,val2,val3], column_title_2 :["string 1","string 2","string 3"], column_title_3 :["string 1a","string 2b","string 3c"], "categories" :["category1","category1","category1"]}}}
```

And I want to import the dictionary into Pandas so it would look like this:

df_Structure_1

```
--------------------------------column_title_1-----column_title_2-----column_title_3
product_name_1---category 1-----val_1         -----string 1      -----string 1a
--------------------------------val_2         -----string 2      -----string 2b
--------------------------------val_3         -----string 3      -----string 3c
-----------------category 2-----val_4         -----string 4      -----string 4d
--------------------------------val_5         -----string 5      -----string 5e
--------------------------------val_6         -----string 6      -----string 6f
product_name_2---category 1a----val_1         -----string 1      -----string 1a
--------------------------------val_2         -----string 2      -----string 2b
--------------------------------val_3         -----string 3      -----string 3c
-----------------category 2b----val_4         -----string 4      -----string 4d
--------------------------------val_5         -----string 5      -----string 5e
--------------------------------val_6         -----string 6      -----string 6f
```

i.e. there is a multi_index of both product names and of categories.

or df_Structure_2

```
--------------------------------column_title_1-----column_title_2-----column_title_3------category
product_name_1------------------val_1         -----string 1      -----string 1a     ------category1
--------------------------------val_2         -----string 2      -----string 2b     ------category1
--------------------------------val_3         -----string 3      -----string 3c     ------category1
--------------------------------val_4         -----string 4      -----string 4d     ------category2
--------------------------------val_5         -----string 5      -----string 5e     ------category2
--------------------------------val_6         -----string 6      -----string 6f     ------category2
product_name_2------------------val_1         -----string 1      -----string 1a     ------category1a
--------------------------------val_2         -----string 2      -----string 2b     ------category1a
--------------------------------val_3         -----string 3      -----string 3c     ------category1a
--------------------------------val_4         -----string 4      -----string 4d     ------category1b
--------------------------------val_5         -----string 5      -----string 5e     ------category1b
--------------------------------val_6         -----string 6      -----string 6f     ------category1b
```

I've tried simply

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(product_dict.items(), orient='index')
```

And many many other approaches such as iterating through the dictionaries to build dataframes. I have not yet made anything work.

Please help with a solution or at least let me know the right terms to search for in the comments.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks @Valentino How did you format the table like that. I always struggle with tables on SO.

Comment: select the text with the mouse and press `{}` on the textbox top bar.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [pandas.DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_dict) doesn't make multiindexed dataframes. Plus, in your case, some of your dictionary keys are index, other are columns, so you need to build the dataframe by yourself.

You can iterate over your dictionaries to make a list of dataframes using the dictionaries at the inner nested level, and then use [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to join them into a single multiindexed dataframe.

Let's start from Structure 2 (`ss2` is the dictionary following Structure 2) which is simpler:

```
df_list2 = [pd.DataFrame(v, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[k], range(len(v[list(v)[0]]))])) for k, v in ss2.items()]
df2 = pd.concat(df_list2)
```

`df_list2` is a list of dataframes, for each one the multindex is already prepared using [pandas.MultiIndex.from_product](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_product), so that when using `concat` the result comes naturally. The MultiIndex has 2 levels: a product name, and a progressive integer for the rows which have the same product name.

Same logic for Structure 1 (here `ss1` is the dictionary`), but here the iteration is more complex since there are going to be 3 levels in the multiindex: product name, category name, and progressive integer.

```
df_list1 = [pd.DataFrame(iv, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[k], [ik], range(len(iv[list(iv)[0]]))])) for k, v in ss1.items() for ik, iv in v.items()]
df1 = pd.concat(df_list1)
```

Comment: Thanks again @Valentino . Could you please break this list comprehension down a bit please? I am struggling to interpret it and I am also getting an error currently: 
`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (800) into shape (80)`

Comment: Does the error comes from `pd.concat` or from the list comprehension?

Comment: This is the first part of the error message (it's quite long) `ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-8684d991453e> in <module>
     13 # >>> pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
     14 
---> 15 df_list2 = [pd.DataFrame(v, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[k], range(len(v[list(v)[0]]))])) for k, v in merged_dict.items()]
     16 df2 = pd.concat(df_list2)` 
The error appears to be on the list comprehension

Comment: Are you sure that all columns have the same length? If not, that may be the cause.